# Accessing Data VIA PDO within a function - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm quite new to PHP, so I apologise in advance for any nauseatingly bad code that I post...

I have created a basic membership system for a fitness bootcamp. I have two SQL tables - "members" and "payments".

I have created a table, and using a loop, I can display all members. Now, I wish to be able to check if the member has paid using the function checkpayment().

This function checks the payments table to see if there is a row that contains a payment for that member id, within the current month and year.

Even when a payment is entered into the payments table, the user still shows as unpaid.

```
function checkpayment($memberid, $month, $year){
    global $db;
            $payments = "SELECT * FROM 'payments' WHERE member_id = :memberid";
            $result = $db->prepare($payments);
            $result->bindParam(':memberid', $memberid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $result->bindParam(':month', $month, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $result->bindParam(':year', $year, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            return $result->fetchColumn();
}
```

Here is the code to display the members:

```
foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM `members`') as $row) {
             $checkpayment = checkpayment($row['id'],10,2014);
             if(!$checkpayment){
              $status = "danger";
              $paid = "Unpaid";
             } else {
              $status = "success";
              $paid = "Paid";
             }
                echo '<tr class="'. $status .'">
                <td>'. $row['id'] .'</td>
                <td>' . $row['first_name'] . '</td>
                <td>' . $row['last_name'] .'</td>
                <td>' . $paid . '</td>
                <td>' . $row['programme'] . '</td>
              </tr>';

            }
```

However, even when a payment row is present, the members still show as unpaid...

Comment: what is the result for checkpayment() please use var_dump for me

Comment: The result is - bool(false)

Comment: Now change fetchColumn() to fetch() try again

Comment: You are attempting to bind parameters not included in the query, namely `:month` and `:year`

Comment: @Steve, yes, I was trying to simplify my query so that it was easier to debug, have removed those statements. Will update question.

Comment: You should not modify your original code based on the answers you get as that would cause the answers not to make sense any more.

Comment: @Hakiko, I did this, still no result.

Comment: @Jeroen, apologies, thanks.

Comment: @user16174 No problem, you can always add updates below your original question to add what you tried and what the results were.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using `prepare` function also you must use `execute()` as far as I know. Try below, if not work I'll update.

[**Here**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) you can see some details about `execute()`

```
function checkpayment($memberid, $month, $year){
    global $db;
            $payments = "SELECT * FROM payments WHERE member_id = :memberid";
            $result = $db->prepare($payments);
            $result->bindParam(':memberid', $memberid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $result->execute();//ADD This line
            return $result->fetchColumn();
}
```

Comment: Neither did I until I was debugging my illustration code. Please excuse the sarcasm in my reply but I've found it's the best way to make sure that he, I and anyone else who reads this never make that mistake again!

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong kinds of quotes in your query:

```
$payments = "SELECT * FROM 'payments' WHERE member_id = :memberid";
```

should be:

```
$payments = "SELECT * FROM payments WHERE member_id = :memberid";
```

or:

```
$payments = "SELECT * FROM `payments` WHERE member_id = :memberid";
```

And you should only bind the variables that you are actually using, `:memberid` in this case OR add the other variables to your query. In your case you should obviously do the latter.

To catch these errors, you should set-up PDO to throw exceptions. You can do that by adding this right after you open the database connection:

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting * which returns multiple columns and then PDOStatement::fetch_column which will only return the first. Since this is probably the member id, the result would always be true.

Or at least it would be if you had actually called $result->execute () before trying to read the results! ;-)

This is a prime opportunity for a join:

```
    $month = 1;
    $year = 2014;
    $pdo = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", "xxx", 'xxx');
    $sel = $pdo->prepare ("select * from member as m
left join payments as p
on m.member_id = p.member_id
and p.month = :month
and p.year = :year");
    $sel->bindParam('month', $month, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sel->bindParam('year', $year, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sel->execute ();
    var_dump ($sel->fetchAll ());
```

Results:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["member_id"]=>string(1) "1"
    ["member_name"]=>string(4) "Good"
    ["pmember_id"]=>string(1) "1"
    ["year"]=>string(4) "2014"
    ["month"]=>string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["member_id"]=>string(1) "2"
    ["member_name"]=>string(8) "Deadbeat"
    ["pmember_id"]=>NULL
    ["year"]=>NULL
    ["month"]=>NULL
  }
}
```

As you can see, all members who have not paid for the specified month and year have a pmember_id, year and month of NULL.

I changed the name of the member_id in the payments query so that the fetchAll would work for this illustration.